# Paperclip with has_many through model relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have been trying to upload multiple files using has_many :through relationship.

This are my models:

```
# Multimedia
has_many :content_multimedias 
has_many :contents, through: :content_multimedias

has_attached_file :path

# Content
has_many :content_multimedias 
has_many :multimedias, through: :content_multimedias

accepts_nested_attributes_for :multimedias

# ContentMultimedia 
belongs_to :content
belongs_to :multimedia
```

The relation in the console works great, but when I try to add an image sends me this error

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: path
```

I also added **multimedias** to **attr_accessible** but still errors.